# Bootstrap v5.0.2 Navbar - Remove Shadow/Border/Outline

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to remove `shadow/outline/border` from my navigation bar, I have tried a few CSS variations to try to accomplish this to no avail.

Here is the specific HTML:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm" id="site-navigation">
    <ul class="navbar-nav" id="site-home">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                <img src="build/img/site-logo.png" alt="Home" height="61px" width="155px">
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Socials -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto" id="site-socials">
        <!-- Github -->
        <li class="nav-item socials">
            <a href="" class="btn btn-transparent btn-lg" role="button"> GitHub </a>
        </li>
        <!-- LinkedIn -->
        <li class="nav-item socials">
            <a href="" class="btn btn-transparent btn-lg" role="button"> LinkedIn </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Here is my current css:

```css
.navbar.navbar-expand-sm {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    border: 0;
}

nav#site-navigation {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    border: 0;
}
```

I am using bootstrap v5.0.2, any help would be greatly appreciated (:

Comment: I can't see any shadow and border in your current code. And if you want to remove them somewhere then use `border-0` and `shadow-none` classes.

Answer (score 1):

```
.navbar.navbar-expand-sm {
box-shadow: none !important;
outline: none !important;
-webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
border: 0;
}

nav#site-navigation {
box-shadow: none !important;
outline: none !important;
-webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
border: 0;
}
```

actually bootstrap attributes are stressed by important. so it is very useful to stress important for your css.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I gave the stress important a shot, it doesn't seem to do the trick.